# K3b "Unable to load KCDDB configuration module" lubuntu 18.10

Tags: lubuntu, 32-bit, 18.10, cd, k3b

I'm trying to copy CD tracks to my computer to put on my Android cellphone in lubuntu 18.10 i386 using default software. I couldn't figure out VLC (which wasn't properly playing [the CD](https://saintjoe.com/products/understanding-sacrifice-and-sacrament-in-the-book-of-leviticus)) so I opened K3b (first time using this, too).

I go into settings and it says "Unable to load KCDDB configuration module" in the CDDB tab. I searched Muon Package Manager for 'KCDDB' but there were no results. Searching 'K3b' shows everything installed except extra themes. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 8):

I solved this problem with instruction from #ubuntu's ioria: Install the `kde-config-cddb` package.

1. Close K3b.
2. Click Start > System Tools > Muon Package Manager.
3. Search for `kde-config-cddb`.
4. Install the `kde-config-cddb` package.
5. Try a second time if there is an error the first time with no details provided. (See screenshot below.)
6. Open K3b and go check in Settings if it's working now.

[image: nondescriptive error trying to install the first time]

Comment: Kubuntu 18.04, same issue. This solution worked for me. In short: `sudo apt install kde-config-cddb`